# magento 2 enterprice stock source export not working

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, stock, importexport

Hi i am using magento enterprice when i tried to export stock source  it below message

showing Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon

but after consumer run getting error

bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
bin/magento cron:run

**Error during export process occurred
Error during export process occurred. Please check logs for detail**

[image]

[image]

Comment: php bin/magento cron:run

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal i did in logs There is no data for the export.

Comment: where is the log file? It's not in the standard location /var/log

Answer (score 0):

run this command

php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor

Comment: alredy tried but i am not seeing
 but after consumer run getting error Error during export process occurred Error during export process occurred. Please check logs for detail

Answer (score 0):

Run the below Commands,

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
bin/magento cron:run
```